# Create a table using primary key of another table, that is composed of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design

In hotel booking websites, hotelier creates rate plans for each room category (Super Delux, Suit Room, etc.). And each rate plan has rates based on many things.

**e.g. followings are considered as rate plans**
Super Delux room (Room only) (Payment mode: pay@hotel)
Super Delux room (Room only) (Payment mode: pay now)
Super Delux room (Room + breakfast) (Payment mode: pay@hotel)
Super Delux room (Room + breakfast)(Payment mode: pay now)...

**Followings are the things on which a rate plan varies**
1: Date - Rates can be different for every day
2: Contract Type - Rates on application booking,website booking and travel agents are different
3: Occupancy Type - Rate for single person, 2 people and 3 people are different
4: rate_plan_rate_master is used to save these rates. We need to keep 2 years of data in this table.
.
.
. 
50,000 Hotels * 40 Rate Plans * 6 Occupancy Types * 4 contract types * 730 Days = 8,760,000,000 records

**Followings are the different approaches that I could think of**

#### APPROACH 1

35,040,000,000 Records

.
.
.
**rate_plan_rate_master table**

```
date (pk)  
id_rate_plan (pk/fk)  
contract_type (pk/fk)  
id_occupancy_type (pk/fk)  
rate
```

.
.
.

#### APPROACH 2 : Dont keep occupancies in different tables

5,840,000,000‬ Records

**rate_plan_rate_master** table

```
date (pk)  
id_rate_plan (pk/fk)  
contract_type (pk/fk)  
rate_single  
rate_double  
rate_triple  
rate_extra_child  
rate_extra_adult  
rate_extra_infant
```

.
.
.

#### APPROACH 3 : Create different tables to save rates for different contract types (split table into tables)

1,168,000,000‬ Records in each table

```
rate_plan_rate_master_web  
rate_plan_rate_master_mobile  
rate_plan_rate_master_b2b  
rate_plan_rate_master_travel_agent
```

**Following things will help you understand the requirements :**

1. Occupancy types won't change in the near future. Maybe 1 or 2 types could be added as extra_child2, extra_adult2...
2. Usually not all the hoteliers enter the price for all types of occupancies... Small hotels don't add prices for Triple, Squad, extra_infant, extra_child.
3. Should I use a composite key? Or the primary key of one column and unique constraint on other fields.
4. This table's PK will be passed in booking_details table
5. This table requires only 2 years of data, but that doesn't mean we would remove it once it gets older. We want the data for analytic purposes. So right now what I can think of is that every day we will run a service or job in laravel that will remove 2 years old data from this table and add it somewhere else. If this is a solution please help me where should I send it, another table, CSV file or something else.

Comment: Duplicating the rates for every day doesn't seem like the best thing to do. Why not have start and end date ranges for each set of rates? I would consider using a variation on option 2 but with ranges instead of individual dates.

Comment: Yep- something like option 2

Comment: @nvogel actually the rates keep changing. What if a hotelier enters rates for 10 days. And after couple of hours, change rate for only one day. Then I will have to split 1 row into 3. Plus what would be the primary key?

Comment: @strawberry Occupancy types can go up to 8 or 10. I can just add all the occupancy types (single, double) as columns in *rate_plan_rate_master* table, but there will be many blank entries. But it reduces the total rows tho. If I keep the occupancy types in different tables then there won't be any null entries but it increases the total rows by 8-10 times. Please share your thoughts on this

Comment: Creating 1 or 2 extra ranges is a lot simpler than updating 10s or 100s of day rows. I expect the key could be (date_low, date_hi, id_rate_plan, contract_type).

Comment: @nvogel  https://ibb.co/k8Gmmgg check out this link. Every 2nd or 3rd day has different rates. I don't think it would make that big a difference

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to change the other rates - your query would just find the most applicable rate; either the latest updated, or the one with the smallest covering range window, or the highest applicable rate

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand.. can you explain it again, please?